# add value to existing class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all, I have searched quite some hours to find this.. I presume it has an easy fix but I'm really new to jQuery and Javascript, so I'm here for your help.

**The problem**
I'm working with multiple divs and jQuery ToggleSlide(). I want the script to find the right div to open when I click the corresponding div.

For example, when I click the div 'hackandfly', I want it to open the div 'hackandfly-open'.

**The code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.project-open').hide();
$('.hackandfly, .scanergy, .connecting-food').click(function() {
    $slidah = $(this);
    $slidah.slideToggle();
    $('div.project-open').not($slidah).slideUp();
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content projects">
        <h3>Projects</h3>
        <div class="project project-big hackandfly">
                <h3>Hack and Fly</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="hackandfly-open project-open" style="display: none;">
            <img src="images/schiphol-logo.png" class="img-project-open"> Proin nec elit ac sapien facilisis ultrices. Integer pellentesque ex a luctus fringilla. Aenean in quam quam. Integer gravida quam eget mauris laoreet hendrerit. Vestibulum feugiat ipsum id.
            <br>
            <br>
            Metus aliquet iaculis. Proin massa justo, maximus in tortor et, Proin massa justo, maximus in tortor et. In aliquam laoreet magna et iaculis. Vestibulum vel orci lobortis, elementum nulla eget, porta eros. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
            <br>
            <br>
            Proin massa justo, maximus in tortor et, tincidunt efficitur nibh. Mauris vulputate euismod lorem, vel rutrum ipsum iaculis eu.
        </div>
```

So what I'm looking for, is that when I push 'hackandfly' div, 'scanergy' div or the 'connecting-food' div, I want it to slideToggle the corresponding div that has -open behind it (I have 3 divs with info called hackandfly-open, scanergy-open, connecting-food-open).

I tried some things like:

```
$slidah = $(this).after('-open');
```

And some other stuff but it didn't work. Who can help me?

Cheers!

Comment: Do the divs you're clicking on have _other_ classes as well?

Comment: Add `HTML` in question

Comment: Can you modify your HTML, or is it locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.project-open').hide();
$('.hackandfly, .scanergy, .connecting-food').click(function() {
    $slidah = $($(this).attr('class')+'-open');
    $slidah.slideToggle();
    $('div.project-open').not($slidah).slideUp();
});
});
```

**However**, the above will fail if you have multiple classes. 
A workaround would be to add `data-*` to the clicked elements like

```
<div class="hackandfly other-class" data-class-target="hackandfly-open"></div>
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.project-open').hide();
    $('.hackandfly, .scanergy, .connecting-food').click(function() {
        $slidah = $('.'+$(this).attr('data-class-target'));
        $slidah.slideToggle();
        $('div.project-open').not($slidah).slideUp();
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it doesn't work, unfortunately. See link provided

Comment: @user1291146, can you try my second suggestion(using `data-*` attributes) ?

Comment: You sir, are a boss! Thanks a lot for the quick replies (to everyone), never use this site and the response rate is... FAST! And it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would generate a unique click handler for each class. That way, you can store all the applicable class names in an array:

```
// Creates a new unique click function for each class name
function generateClickHandler(className) {
    return function(e) {
        // select the open class here
        $slidah = $('.'+className+'-open');
        $slidah.slideToggle();
        $('div.project-open').not($slidah).slideUp();
    };
}
// Iterate over all the class names and add a new function for each
var clsList = ["hackandfly", "scanergy", "connecting-food"];
$.each(clsList, function(className) {
    $("."+className).click(generateClickHandler(className));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('.hackandfly, .scanergy, .connecting-food').click(function() {
    $slidah = $("."+$(this).attr('class')+"-open");
    $slidah.slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't seem to work. See the new link provided for visual feedback

Comment: That's a start, but it's only going to work if the clicked element has one class.

Answer (score 0):

If you added a wrapper around each section like so:

```
    <div class="content projects">
        <h3>Projects</h3>
        <div class="project-wrapper">
            <div class="project project-big hackandfly">
                    <h3>Hack and Fly</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="hackandfly-open project-open" style="display: none;">
                {...}
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

you could use `parent` and `find` to get the corresponding element as follows:

```
$('.hackandfly, .scanergy, .connecting-food').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.project-open').eq(0).slideToggle();
}
```